# Does google have restrictions on the using Xpath for find the form by id?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

All:

Does Google some how prevent searching of elements by id using Xpath?

```
    WebDriver wbdriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();


    wbdriver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oB5BVNXnOKzV8gePnYDQBA");

    WebElement element = wbdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='gbqf']"));
```

I found other tags by name or tagname.  However, I've been trying for a really long time to find by Xpath using id.

Does google have restrictions that prevents the aforementioned code from working?

Thanks in advance

**Update with Answer**

I used FirefoxDriver instead of HtmlUnitDriver

WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: No. However you've got two problems: not using a real browser and using a complicated site.

Comment: r u stating that the problem is because I'm using HtmlUnitDriver ?

Comment: More of a suggestion to try it in Chrome, before assigning the problem to Google/Selenium.

Comment: If you're wanting to use a headless browser I would really recommend the PhantomJS/Ghostdriver package over HTMLUnitDriver. The later isn't without its faults when there are JavaScript errors on a page mind.

Comment: What error do you get that makes you say it does not work? FWIW, I prefer to use XPath only if the other methods cannot do what I want to do or can't do it without convoluted code. Here I'm wondering why not just search by id...

Answer (score 2):

XPath should work if Id is working to find elements. May be you got the Xpath wrong.
Here is what I found as XPath from Google Search page:

```
//*[@id="gbqfq"]
```

Hope this helps!